# Demonstrate change of predictor variable for a time series

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, change-point

I have the following problem:

Assume there are three time series $h(t)$, $g(t)$ and $f(t)$.

The hypothesis is that prior to $t_1$: $h(t)=a\cdot f(t-t_2)$ 
and after $t_1$: $h(t)=b \cdot g(t-t_3)$.

Now the question is are there statistical or mathematical tests that would allow me to determine $t_1$? And prove that the assumed relationship between $h(t)$, $g(t)$ and $f(t)$ is correct?

Comment: Dear adunaic, I raised the question earlier. You indicated you could provide an aswer. Would you be so kind to elaborate your promised answer? The discussion you linked does not provide a complete answer to the problem. Kind regards @adunaic

Comment: wouldn't "determine $t_1$" be a matter of estimation rather than testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [2010 JASA paper](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~zhangxiany/JASA-2010.pdf) which seems to use a KS test.

In general there is a difference between detecting points and testing whether a detected point is *valid*.

Comment: Well, I tried some change point tests but they are unable to identify the change point because it is not prominent. However, I was hoping to find a test that would compute the cross-correlation between the three time series and identify the point where the cross-correlation coefficient suddenly decreases between h(t) and f(t) and maximizes for h(t) and g(t). But that would require some kind of iterative numerical operation...furthermore it would require knowledge abouot t2 and t3.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds like a picewise regression, where one part of a response variable vector is modeled using **a** coefficient, while the other part is modeled with **b** coefficient. You just to the task one more regressor variable. You cab use grid search over **t** while building two linear models, and the stopping criterion would be maximizing the t-statistic respective to the estimates of **aa and b** in both models.